# PHP form submit, get origin url in backend

Tags: php, forms

I want to get the url from which form was submitted. This is very easy to achieve using hidden input
We can get full page url in php like

```
<?php $fullURL = "https://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}"; ?>
```

and store it in input

```
<form>
      ...
      <input type='hidden' value='<?php echo $fullURL; ?>'/>
      ..
```

.

But this can be easily manipulated by client. Is there any way to know origin of the form in the backend?

Comment: Use [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php)

Comment: $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];